# Make menu open url links in webkit and other times open views

Tags: swift, swiftui

friends!
I’m new using swift and I have a problem, may be easy to solve, but I spent hours trying…

I have this app to open webpages when click on a link in the menu bar. It is working great. The problem is that some menu should open views not webpages.

For example, menu item “about” should open an aboutView containing app version…

I try to call AboutView() but no success.
Any ideas how to change my code to allow sometimes webview pages and sometimes open activities (views)?
Thanks!

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isSideMenuOpen = true
    @State private var webViewURL: URL? = URL(string: "https://www.example.com")
    
    var body: some View {
        
        // BannerView()
        
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ZStack {
                    // Your main content view
                    Color.white // Replace with your content view
                    
                    // Side menu overlay
                    if isSideMenuOpen {
                        Color.black.opacity(0.5).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                withAnimation {
                                    isSideMenuOpen.toggle()
                                }
                            }
                    }
                    
                    // Side menu
                    VStack {
                        if isSideMenuOpen || geometry.size.width > 800 {
                            SideMenuView(isOpen: $isSideMenuOpen, didSelectURL: { url in
                                webViewURL = url
                                isSideMenuOpen = true
                            })
                            .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
                        }
                        
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("App"))
            }
                
            .background(
                    
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: webViewURL.map { WebView(url: $0) },
                    isActive: Binding<Bool>(
                        get: { webViewURL != nil },
                        set: { _ in webViewURL = nil }
                    ),
                    label: EmptyView.init
                )
                    
            )
                
            
        }
    }
}

struct SideMenuView: View {
    @Binding var isOpen: Bool
    var didSelectURL: (URL) -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
            Button(action: {
                if let url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com") {
                    didSelectURL(url)
                }
            }) {
                Text("page 1")
            }
            Button(action: {
                // Handle other menu item taps
            }) {
                Text("page 2")
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                AboutView() 
            }) {
                Text("About")
            }
            
            
            
            // Add more menu items as needed
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .background(Color.white)
        .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
    }
}

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let url: URL

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return WKWebView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        uiView.load(request)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
Button(action: {
    AboutView() 
}) {
    Text("About")
}
```

with:

```
NavigationLink {
    AboutView()
} label: {
    Text("About")
}
```